# Magento ver. 1.9.3.8 customer/user login didn't working in chrome? But working in firefox and Edge

Tags: magento-1.9, login, customer-account

My magento store customer login is just reloading the page in chrome. I have checked the code flow, Everything is good. Like the session is setting, Even its going to customer/account/index. But returning back.

Kindly Help.

Comment: I am also getting same issue. did you find the solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

If your using local host.. use 127.0.0.1 or your local ip  instead of http://localhost/magento-url  . magento have deprecated the http://localhost/magento-url